# Why does new data frame column populate all values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, df, with 2 columns. When I create a 3rd column and try to update the first value only, it populates the entire column instead. Could someone explain why that is and what the solution for it is?

```
#Create data frame with 2 columns and 4 observations
name <- c("Bob", "Lauren", "Joe", "Chris")
age <- c(45, 34, 54, 12)
df <- data.frame(name, age)

#Create new column
df$occupation[1] <- "Builder"
```

The code above produces the following results:

```
    df
    name age occupation
1    Bob  45    Builder
2 Lauren  34    Builder
3    Joe  54    Builder
4  Chris  12    Builder
```

The desired result are:

```
 df
    name age occupation
1    Bob  45    Builder
2 Lauren  34       <NA>
3    Joe  54       <NA>
4  Chris  12       <NA>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `occupation` does not yet exists is created, recycling the first value. Here is how I would do this.

```
name <- c("Bob", "Lauren", "Joe", "Chris")
age <- c(45, 34, 54, 12)
df <- data.frame(name, age, occupation=NA)

df$occupation <- NA
df$occupation[1] <- "Builder"
```

or

```
df <- data.frame(name, age, occupation=NA)
df$occupation[1] <- "Builder"
```

Note that

```
df <- data.frame(name, age)
df$occupation[2] <- "Builder"
```

also does work as you expected. It recycles `c(NA, "Builder")` (thanks to @joran for pointing this out).

Comment: I think if you run your very last example in a clean session you may find that it doesn't work _quite_ as the OP expected.

Comment: Thanks @RobertH. I initialized the new column like you recommended with 'df$occupation <- NA' and that did the trick. I didn't include the occupation vector in the 'data.frame()' function but it still worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could use a little more clarification.

Consider the setup:

```
name <- c("Bob", "Lauren", "Joe", "Chris")
age <- c(45, 34, 54, 12)
df <- data.frame(name, age)
```

and now look at what happens when we do:

```
debugonce(`$<-.data.frame`)
> df$x[1] <- "a"
debugging in: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = "a")
debug: {
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    class(x) <- NULL
    nrows <- .row_names_info(x, 2L)
    if (!is.null(value)) {
        N <- NROW(value)
        if (N > nrows) 
            stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
                "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), 
                domain = NA)
        if (N < nrows) 
            if (N > 0L && (nrows%%N == 0L) && length(dim(value)) <= 
                1L) 
                value <- rep(value, length.out = nrows)
            else stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
                "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), 
                domain = NA)
        if (is.atomic(value) && !is.null(names(value))) 
            names(value) <- NULL
    }
    x[[name]] <- value
    class(x) <- cl
    return(x)
}
```

Note that this was called with `value = "a"` and eventually we're going to simply run `x[[name]] <- value`, so "a" is recycled along every row.

That seems simple enough, but what happens when we do (be sure to wipe out the column `x` between each of these!):

```
debugonce(`$<-.data.frame`)
> df$x[2] <- "a"
debugging in: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = c(NA, "a"))
#Rest snipped...
```

Oho! This time it was called with `value = c(NA,"a")`, so contrary to RobertH's answer above we see that the recycling in fact yields:

```
> df
    name age    x
1    Bob  45 <NA>
2 Lauren  34    a
3    Joe  54 <NA>
4  Chris  12    a
```

Confused? What if we try:

```
debugonce(`$<-.data.frame`)
> df$x[3] <- "a"
debugging in: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = c(NA, NA, "a"))
```

Hmmm. This one ends in an error, because the recycling fails.

For completion:

```
debugonce(`$<-.data.frame`)
> df$x[4] <- "a"
debugging in: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = c(NA, NA, NA, "a"))
```

And that one results in:

```
> df
    name age    x
1    Bob  45 <NA>
2 Lauren  34 <NA>
3    Joe  54 <NA>
4  Chris  12    a
```

So what's going on here? Well, remember that nonexistent columns of a data frame (or nonexistent elements of a list, really) are treated as `NULL`. And so we're referencing the 1st, 2nd, etc. element of `NULL`.

Now run:

```
> `[<-`(NULL,1,1)
[1] 1
> `[<-`(NULL,2,1)
[1] NA  1
> `[<-`(NULL,3,1)
[1] NA NA  1
> `[<-`(NULL,4,1)
[1] NA NA NA  1
```

and you can start to see how the various calls are being pieced together.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the expected output if you don't want to initialize the variable before:

```
df[1,"occupation"] <- "Builder"
```

I have no idea why...

Comment: You can step through the (very long) `'[<-.data.frame'` to see exactly why this works, but good luck keeping track of all the variables names with only 1-3 characters! ;)